# "It is time + you + do"

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure

> Which means you're technically an adult, don't you think ***it's time
>   you move*** on from primitive constructs such as popularity?

I saw this line in a tv-series. I thought this construction "it's time + you + do" is grammatically wrong.

I suppose this version is the correct one:

> "...***it's time for you to move*** on from primitive constructs such
>   as popularity?

Comment: There should be a semicolon after *an adult*, not a comma.

Answer (score 1):

The general construction is:

> It's time [something].

These sentences are fine:

> You eat.
>   You move on.

By extension, so are these:

> It's time *you eat*.
>   It's time *you move on*.

---

There nothing wrong with the longer version (*it's time <sup>for</sup> you <sup>to</sup> move on*), but the shorter version is also acceptable.

Comment: Thank you. Some BrE speakers say that should be "moved on". Is this one of the American English and British English difference?

Comment: @TalhaÖzden Yes, you can also say *it's time you **moved** on*. This has nothing to do with US versus UK English that I know of. I have heard both versions used in both places. *Move on* is more active, while *moved on* is more descriptive. At least that's my immediate impression, but I'd have to give it more thought. (A discussion of that difference would require a separate question and answer.)